# PowerBI / DAX – SWITCH IN using a list containing wildcards

Tags: powerbi, dax

Premise:
In PowerBI I'm trying to  create a new column
in order to apply several general categories to a column containing several hundred category items.
It is a merged table from several locations with about 5M+ rows.
Some of the categorization has been done in PowerQuery during data transformation.

Currently, I need to prototype the outcome, so in the future I could talk to the database maintainers, in order to create keys or adjust the SQL queries used to generate proper datasets to make this task easier.

The data is "type text" and contains mixed text only entries and mixed(numbers+text) entries.

So far I have partial success with the SWITCH function.

For example the function I'm trying to accomplish my sorting:

```
CategoryGeneral =
var _Abs = {"A1"; "A2" ... "A10"}
var _Mlt = {"Ba"; "Bb" ... "Be"}
var _Dir = {"A0?-1*"; "A0?-2*"; "A0?-3*"; "A1?-1*"; "A1?-2*"; "A1?-3*"}
/* the "mask" "A1?-1*" can easily cover a group of thousands of elements, where "?" is 1..9, */
/* and "-1*" is 100..19999 */
return
SWITCH(
TRUE;
[Category] in _Abs; "Absolute"; /* => this works fine */
[Category] in _Mlt; "Multiscale"; /* => works fine too */
[Category] in _Dir; "Directory"; /* => this evaluates to "Undefined Category" instead of "Directory" */
/* else */
"Undefined Category"
)
```

*EDIT for clarification [result is not error, but else condition]

Comment: Does it cause an error or just doesn't get any hits?

Comment: Sorry,
I should have been more clear.
`[Category] in _Dir; "Directory";`
 does not evaluate.

I get the else value "Undefined Category" , instead of "Directory".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CONTAINSSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/containsstring-function-dax) function supports wildcards.

Try:

```
COUNTROWS(FILTER(_Dir; CONTAINSSTRING([Category]; [Value]))) > 0; "Directory";
```

in place of:

```
[Category] in _Dir; "Directory";
```

[image]

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I am mixing switch conditions with countrows?

`[Category] in _Mlt; "Multiscale";
COUNTROWS(FILTER( _Dir, CONTAINSSTRING([Category], _Dir))) > 0; "Directory";
"undefined category")`

This results in an error.

I wonder what should be used as the [Value] ?

Comment: Updated my answer - tricky with the switch of `,` and `;` depending on Regional Settings. Swap any `,` (commas) with `;` (semi-colons)

Comment: Did that automatically ;)

All `,` replaced with `;`   .

However, there's still an error: "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected".

Comment: It needs to be `[Value]` not `_Dir`. Use exactly as it is in the answer. `COUNTROWS(FILTER(_Dir; CONTAINSSTRING([Category]; [Value]))) > 0; "Directory";`

Comment: Sam, thank you very much!

It works!

I was not sure about the COUNTROWS function at first, but did a bit of reading up on it, and apparently even in the documentation it is stated: 
_ This function can be used to count the number of rows in a base table, but more often is used to count the number of rows that result from filtering a table, **or applying context to a table.** _
from: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countrows-function-dax)

Who would've thought?

Comment: Great, please help mark answer as Accepted for the benefit of all (the checkmark below the voting buttons).